# "error stray '#'" in program while compiling

Tags: c

I have a simple program, but it gets into an infinite loop while compiling.

Here is the code.

```
void load_levels(char *path) {

    FILE* fp = FOPEN(path, "r");
    char* line;
    char* buffer;
    LEVEL *level;
    while(fgets(line, 1024, fp) != EOF) {
        fgets(line, 1024, fp);
        printf("%s", line);
    }

    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Don't blindly copy paste code from pdf, or any other web sources

Comment: fgets return a pointer not a char, you should change `!= EOF` to `!= NULL` (or simply `while (fgets())`). And I think it's `fopen` not `FOPEN`.

Comment: There are many errors in this program. For example, you should #include <stdio>, fopen should be spelled "fopen", not "FOPEN", and if this is intended to be a complete program, you need a main function.

Comment: no it is not intended program,,, I have main in other file.I have tried every of your advices but it still doesnt work.

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "infinites loop while compiling". Do you mean that you get compilation errors? In that case, which ones? Or does the compiler crash, hang or malfunction in some way? In that case, exactly how? Or does your program compile, but then when it executes, is that when you get the infinite loop?

Comment: levels.dat:16:287: error: stray ‘#’ in program
compiling gives mi these errors still in loop while I dont input control c.

Comment: You're compiling your data input file. You don't want to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't allocated any memory for `line`.  Use `char line[1024]`.  You should also check against NULL not EOF.

Comment: Either way, he will still need to allocate memory.

Answer (score 1):

There are many errors in the code you have posted, but the reason for the compiler error you have quoted in the title of the question is as follows.

Your program is parsing Sokoban levels that appear in your file "levels.dat" in lines like this:

```
    chicago;addie;story begins here;-----#####-----------|-----#@$.#-----------|-----#####-----------
```

You have accidentally added this file to your project as a C source code file, and the compiler is complaining about the first #, which is the point at which if fails to parse as C.

Remove this file from your project and this error will go away. You can then fix the other errors the compiler will highlight in your C code.